Azure Devops: How to Enable Moving Items in Backlogs ( Move to Position )?
I've been assigned to a couple of Azure DevOps Organizations. In one of them, I can drag and drop work items (stories, bugs, tasks, etc.) and when I right click the option to "Move to Position" is enabled.
In my other organization, this functionality is completlely absent.  I cannot drag and drop; I cannot "Move to Position".  I otherwise have all available "Project Permissions".  I cannot find any setting that prevents me from prioritizing and moving the order of position of my items in backlog or sprints.
Is there some setting that me or my other administrators are missing that would enable this functionality?

I agree with Rui's answer; the issue likely relates to your access level. To use the drag-and-drop feature for work items, you'll need to have at least basic access.

You probably have Stakeholder access level, which has limited access to Azure Boards and collaboration tools.
You can check the access level for your user in "Organization Settings > Users":


Thank you.  I couldn't find this documentation by searching for "Move to Position".  Exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

@ADOUser glad to help :-) Please consider accepting my answer.

Done!  I have done this!
